# ProgressBar progess not uploaded with firestore progress value. (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am making sudoku multiplayer app in which i have to update the progress of the game of the opponent in the game of player. I can upload the progress to firestore successfully but cannot retrieve the progress of the other player. Following is the code snapshot.

```
public class PercentAdapter(options: FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Percent1>) :
FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Percent1, PercentAdapter.PercentHolder>(options) {

class PercentHolder(itemView:View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    var per : Int = 0
    lateinit var progressBar2 : ProgressBar
    lateinit  var p:PlaySudokuActivity
    init {
        //super(itemView)
        per = (itemView as PlaySudokuActivity).progressBar.getProgress()
        p = itemView as PlaySudokuActivity
        //progressBar2 = (itemView as PlaySudokuActivity).progressBar2

    }
}

public override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PercentHolder, position:Int, model:Percent1) {
    holder.per = model.getPer()
    holder.p.progressBar2.setIndeterminate(false)
    holder.p.progressBar2.setMax(0)
    holder.p.progressBar2.setMax(100)
    holder.p.progressBar2.setProgress(model.getPer())
}

public override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType:Int): PercentAdapter.PercentHolder {
    var v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_play_sudoku, parent, false)
    return PercentAdapter.PercentHolder(v)
}

public fun deleteItem(position:Int) {
    getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getReference().delete()
}
}
```

My MainActivity is playSudokuActivity in which I have written the recyclerview and added the above adapter for it to work. Following is the code for it.

```
public lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
public lateinit var progressBar2 : ProgressBar

public var db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
private lateinit var perRef : CollectionReference
public lateinit var adapter: PercentAdapter

OnCreate() {
....
        perRef = db.collection("Percentage")
        recyclerView = RecyclerView(this)
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayout.VERTICAL, false)
        var layout2 = ConstraintLayout(this) as ConstraintLayout
        progressBar2 = ProgressBar(this,null,android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);
        progressBar2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progressBar2.setMax(100)
        progressBar2.setProgress(0)
        progressBar2.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(
            Color.BLACK, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

        var params2 = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(100,250) as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
        //params.topToTop = top_row.id
        //params.bottomToBottom = mistakes_row.id
        params2.setMargins(450, 0, 0, 0)
        layout2.addView(progressBar2,params2);
        layout2.addView(recyclerView)
        addContentView(layout2, params2);


        setUpRecyclerView()
    }

private fun setUpRecyclerView() {
    var query:Query = perRef.orderBy("per", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)

    var options:FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Percent1> = FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Percent1>().
        setQuery(query, Percent1::class.java).build()

    adapter = PercentAdapter(options)
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter)
}
OnStart() {
 ...
 adapter.startListening()
 ...
}
OnStop() {
 ...
 adapter.stopListening()
 ...
}
```